# How to get raw BLE 'manufacturer specific data' on Android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Essentially I have a BLE scanner on Android and iOS listening for BLE packets in my area. On iOS, I am getting an object of 'advertisementData' which represents a nested property of 'fCBAdvDataManufacturerData' which displays the proper packet hex value in a format such as: **f0g219 02388 02939 02384 00000** for example

On Android, in the manufacturer object, I am receiving a SparseArray which contains the data such as: {6=[42, 75, -112, 75, -34]} of varying lengths.

Is there anyway on Android to view the RAW advertisement packet data in the same way? I need the hex value just like iOS and have looked everywhere for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try to submit a code next time, it'll make it much more easier to look at what you have done already.

1. First of all you'll need to obtain the scanRecord from the ScanCallBack into a byte array:
   *byte[] mScanRecord = result.getScanRecord().getBytes();*
2. Then create a string with the actual advertisement size:
   *final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(advertisementData.length);*
3. Go over the byte array to populate the new string using char casting:
   *for (byte byteChar : advertisementData) {                stringBuilder.append((char) byteChar);}*
4. Convert the byte array to string if you wish
   *String advData = stringBuilder.toString();*

Hope I helped

Comment: what is "advertusmentData" here?